# Wrongful dismissal due to lack of performance?

Tags: united-kingdom, termination, dismissal

I was let go today due to "performance being not of the required standard that the seniority of your role and pay grade dictates."

I had been working with the company since 18th December 2019 and should have finished my 3 month probation in March. Now I was never given a proper meeting to discuss probation, I was told that it's being sorted out. Shortly after, a coworker was let go. Cited was performance issues with the employee. I inquired about it with my boss, telling him that I was worried that it had to do with the Coronavirus crisis. I was told that it was purely based on performance grounds. I asked how I was doing, since I hadn't heard anything back about my probation, and was told that he was really happy with my performance.

Fast forward to last Friday (22 May) I had a rough few weeks and was told by my boss that my performance was worrying and that I really need to pick it up. I had recently been put on a piece or work that ended up being a ton more work than initially intended. He asked me what measures I intend to take and I asked to be put on more smaller tasks so I can bounce back from this dip in performance and he agreed it was the right choice.

As of Wednesday 27 May I have been let go, citing performance reason and my boss stating in a phone call, that there was no way he could see me come back from this.

I do feel like I wasn't given a chance to actually improve but I also understand I had not been there for very long. Do I have any chance to sort this out in some way or is the correct step to take it on the chin and move on to the next venture and give 110%?

Comment: "I asked how I was doing, since I hadn't heard anything back about my probation, and was told that he was really happy with my performance." do you have any proof of that? Was that in person? On the phone?

Comment: This was on the phone. I have done a lot of reading since and have picked up that after conversations like that you should send that person an email detailing everything that was talked about to have it in writing. Sadly there was a performance drop in the last 4 weeks which is what I'm being let go for.

Comment: Okay and please apologize me for being blunt, but can the claim of lack of performance be true? If not, why do you think you were let go?

Comment: Like I said, there was a performance drop due to me picking up a piece of work that was probably too difficult for me. I failed to flag this up quick enough sadly, to where it hurt the team because they had to help me a lot. I'm starting to see the issue though, they have grounds to prove that my performance dropped and can prove it. No matter how unfair it feels, as far as I read there aren't any laws about this. So I guess there is nothing I can do?

Comment: I recommend reading through https://www.gov.uk/dismissal but given that you yourself admit that there were performance issues I don't think you have much of a runway, especially with such short tenure. But keep in mind that I am just a random opinion on the internet.

Comment: The only that stood out was this paragraph: "Before taking any action, your employer should:

follow disciplinary procedures - for example, warn you that your work is not satisfactory.
give you a chance to improve - for example, by training you". Because it all happened so quickly, this stood out to me, but again I don't know if it would help anything.

Comment: You were warned on 22nd of May, and as things didn't improve, they moved further with dismissal. I don't mean to sound brutal, please don't take it as so, but the workplace is not a kindergarden, you are being paid to deliver work, and if you cannot do that and the company thinks that they are better without you (either because they can replace you fast, or it's just not worth the money to keep you) then they have the right to fire you. They don't need to endlessly give you chances or spend fortune on trainig. Best to use this time to reflect, brush up CV and focus that energy on job hunting.

Comment: I understand that, but as I work in Software Development, 2 or 3 working is hardly a time where I can show that my performance increased. Like I said I do think that I am able to learn a lot from this going forward and since they have proof of my performance dropping that there isn't much I can do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grounds for unfair dismissal? (UK)](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/158656/grounds-for-unfair-dismissal-uk)

Answer (score 5):

As you were employed after the 6th of April 2012, and haven't been dismissed due to your political opinions or affiliation, and have been employed for less than 2 years, [you do not have any grounds to claim unfair dismissal](https://www.gov.uk/dismissal/what-to-do-if-youre-dismissed).

Comment: The protected reasons for dismissal are wider than just "political opinions or affiliation" and include the obvious things like sex, race, religion etc but other than that, this is correct.